# sqlalchemy session with autocommit=True does not commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, commit

I'm trying to use a session with autocommit=true to create a row in a table, and it does not seem to be working.  The row is not saved to the table.

```
import os

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, String

db_hostname    = os.environ['DB_HOSTNAME']
db_username    = os.environ['DB_USERNAME']
db_password    = os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
db_servicename = os.environ['DB_SERVICENAME']

engine_string = f"postgresql://{db_username}:{db_password}@{db_hostname}:5432/{db_servicename}"

engine = create_engine(engine_string, isolation_level='REPEATABLE READ',
    poolclass=sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool
)

base = declarative_base()

class Testing(base):
    __tablename__ = 'testing'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    comment = Column(String)

base.metadata.create_all(engine)

S1 = sessionmaker(engine)
with S1() as session:
    test1 = Testing(name="Jimmy", comment="test1")
    session.add(test1)
    session.commit()

S2 = sessionmaker(engine, autocommit=True)
with S2() as session:
    test2 = Testing(name="Johnny", comment="test2")
    session.add(test2)
```

In this code, the first row with name="Jimmy" and an explicit `session.commit()` is saved to the table.

But the second row with name="Johnny" is not saved.  Specifying `autocommit=True` on the session appears to have no effect.

What is the cause?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you enable the `SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1` environment variable you will see

> RemovedIn20Warning: The Session.autocommit parameter is deprecated and will be removed in SQLAlchemy version 2.0. …

The "2.0 way" to accomplish that "autocommit" behaviour is to do

```py
S2 = sessionmaker(engine)
with S2() as session, session.begin():
    test2 = Testing(name="Johnny", comment="test2")
    session.add(test2)
    # no explicit session.commit() required
```

The changes will automatically be committed when the context manager (`with` block) exits, provided that no errors have occurred.

Comment: This will be good to know when I upgrade, but for now I'm using sqlalchemy 1.4.39.

Comment: From what I can see, your second example has never worked. I get the same results with SQLA 1.4.0, and SQLA 1.3.24 barfs on the context manager: `with S1() as session:` throws `AttributeError: __enter__`

Comment: Also, the "2.0 way" does indeed work in 1.4.

Comment: I wonder what the `autocommit=True` in my code actually accomplished, if anything.

Comment: TBH, I don't really know, except that autocommit-like behaviour had evolved into a bit of a mess and Mike (@zzzeek) was very keen to make it go away to the greatest extent possible. (I got involved with the SQLA project just as the big push to build out 1.4 was in full swing.)

Comment: Some background here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#library-level-but-not-driver-level-autocommit-removed-from-both-core-and-orm